Legend fails to show a category in ggplot when this category only has partial values
I have a reproducible code that generates three independent datasets and a combined dataset mydata. The dataset3 have less values, especially missing some values for certain n categories.
mydata1 <- data.frame("model" = rep("A", 1000), "n" = sample.int(10, 1000, replace = T), "n1" = seq(1,1000), "values" = rnorm(1000))
mydata2 <- data.frame("model" = rep("B", 1000), "n" = sample.int(10, 1000, replace = T), "n1" = seq(1,1000), "values" = rnorm(1000))
mydata3 <- data.frame("model" = rep("C", 500), "n" = c(rep(6,100),rep(7,100),rep(8,100),rep(9,100),rep(10,100)), "n1" = seq(1,500), "values" = rnorm(500))
mydata <- rbind(mydata1, mydata2, mydata3)

fig_list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(sort(unique(mydata$n)))) {
    data <- mydata[which(mydata$n == sort(unique(mydata $n))[i]),]
    fig_list[[i]] <- ggplot2::ggplot(data , aes(x = n1, y = values, colour = model)) +
                      geom_line(size = 0.6) +
                      labs(title = paste0("n = ", sort(unique(mydata$n))[i]), x = "n1", y = "values") +
                      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10))  
}

fig_all <- ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = fig_list, ncol = 2, nrow = ceiling(length(fig_list)/2), common.legend = TRUE, legend = "top")
ggpubr::annotate_figure(fig_all, top = text_grob(paste0("All the plots are here.")))

The ggplot produced a plot below across all n but the legend fails to show model C, but the curves (in blue) are still present for subfigures n=6 to n=10, though they are not available for n=1 to n=5.

I still want the model C to be shown in the legend on the top along with model A and model B so that the reader may know what the blue curves represent. How can I make it?

Since model C is in the last plot, you could reverse the list before plotting (ggarrange takes the legend from the first plot in the list when common.legend is TRUE).
ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist=fig_list[rev(1:length(fig_list))], 
                  ncol = 2, nrow = ceiling(length(fig_list)/2), 
                  common.legend = TRUE, legend = "top")



Yes, thank you for clarifications!

Personally I would simply use facetting:
set.seed(123)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = n1, y = values, colour = model)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.6) +
  facet_wrap(~n,
    labeller = labeller(n = \(x) paste0("n = ", x)),
    axes = "all",
    ncol = 2
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10),
    strip.background.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "top"
  ) +
  labs(x = "n1", y = "values", title = "All the plots are here.")
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.


But if you prefer separate plots you could achieve your desired result by fixing or setting the limits= of the color scale to include all models and by adding show.legend=TRUE to geom_line(), which since ggplot2 >= 3.5.0 is required to show a legend key for unused levels .
library(ggpubr)

fig_list <- list()
for (i in sort(unique(mydata$n))) {
  data <- mydata[mydata$n == i, ]
  fig_list[[i]] <- ggplot(data, aes(x = n1, y = values, colour = model)) +
    geom_line(size = 0.6, show.legend = TRUE) +
    scale_color_discrete(limits = unique(mydata$model)) +
    labs(title = paste0("n = ", i), x = "n1", y = "values") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10))
}

fig_all <- ggarrange(
  plotlist = fig_list, ncol = 2, nrow = ceiling(length(fig_list) / 2),
  common.legend = TRUE, legend = "top"
)
annotate_figure(fig_all, top = text_grob(paste0("All the plots are here.")))


